# PHP Как добавить свойство классу?

Tags: php

Свойства класса - это названия столбцов в базе(т.е. класс типа MODEL)

Столбец в базе MYSQL и Elasticsearch называется `18+`

я пробовал

```
class CategoryElastic extends ElasticModel
{
 public static function putStaticProperty(string $name,$value)
 {
   static::${$name} = $value;
 }
}
CategoryElastic::putStaticProperty('18+', null);
```

Но это лишь вызывает ошибку та как свойство изначально не определено

Идет обращение к свойствам класса через [ReflectionClass::getProperties()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) и вытаскивается их имя через [::getName()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reflectionproperty.getname.php)

Comment: не обязательно хоть какое, чтобы в ReflectionClass::getProperties() оно появилось

Comment: для доступа к динамическим свойствам вы можете использовать `ReflectionObject`

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, вы не можете добавить статическое поле по время выполнения.

Если же не приипиальна статичность, то можно воспользоваться [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
class Foo {
    public function addProp($name, $val){
        
        $this->$name = $val;
        //    ^     ^
        // Скобки не нужны
    }
}


$foo = new Foo();

$foo->addProp('18+', 'bar');

$props = get_object_vars($foo);

var_dump($props);
```

Или [`ReflectionObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionobject.php), как предложил Максим Степанов

```
class Foo {
    public function addProp($name, $val){
        
        $this->$name = $val;
        
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

$foo->addProp('18+', 'bar');

$reflect = new ReflectionObject ($foo);
$props = $reflect->getProperties();

var_dump($props);
```